# Best way to search list with another list?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, search

I have a large HashSet list named `resultList` (about million records).

Which I need to find a match in a dictionary list with 10.000 records. Not necessary that there will be a match.

On a 12 thread CPU, this takes about 40-50 seconds.
I'm continuously loading new data to the `sampleList` and comparing them to the `resultList` list.

My question is, can this be done any faster or more elegant?

Here is my code:

```
HashSet<string> resultList = new HashSet<string>()
{
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000002",
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000003",
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000004",
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000005"
    //... this list is about million records
};

Dictionary<string, string> sampleList = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
   { "0000000003000000300000000000000000000005", "This is a value"  },
   { "0000000000100000000000002000000800000001", "This is a value 1"  },
   { "0000000000000000000000000000000000000004", "This is what I'm trying to match" },
   { "0000000200000000100000000000000000000000", "This is a value 2" },
   { "0000005000000000000000000050000000000004", "This is a value 3" },
   { "0000000080000000000200000000000000000004", "This is a value 4" },
   { "0000000000200000000000000000800000000004", "This is a value 5" }
   //... this list is about 10.000 records
};

//first try to find any match - found that Any is faster than Where and the chance to find a match is little, so...
if (resultList.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(MaxDegreeOfParallelism).Any(x => sampleList.Any(y => x == y.Key)))
{
    //then if there is a match, fetch it.
    foreach (var found in resultList.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(MaxDegreeOfParallelism).Where(x => sampleList.Any(y => x == y.Key)))
    {
        //do something with the found matches
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [`Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: what is a format of key?

Comment: I'd iterate the dictionary since it has fewer values and search for matching keys in the hash set instead.

Comment: Are they really string values ?

Comment: @Selvin the format is pretty much the same I gave in my code sample in initial question

Comment: Or maybe even [`IntersectWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.intersectwith?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Generic_HashSet_1_IntersectWith_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__)?

Comment: ok (i assume decimal numbers as string)so it can be represented as long (first 18 chars) long next 18 and long rest ... then searching should be faster

Comment: @Franck in fact, they are hex values, but I had to hide that in my code sample - I think it's not relevant, I'm operating with strings as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Also the `Any` check is faster by itself, but not when you end up doing the `Where` when it's true and when it's false that means it had to iterate the entire thing so might as well just go straight to the `Where`.

Comment: @Selvin but then I have to do recalculation from hex strings to long on a set of a million and then some 10.000 records before I even try to search.

Comment: @juharr that would be true, but the chance to find a match is very very small

Comment: @ZoharPeled this would be ok, if I had same objects right?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand the question. Anyway, Johnathan gave you a good answer - why don't you try it?

Comment: @Rumplin `IntersectWith` here would be `O(n + m)`, with `m` being the length of `sampleList`, as the `KeyCollection` would be converted to a `HashSet` before performing the intersection.

Comment: @Rumplin Knowing the type as `string` was important for the optimal compare. `string` once sorted can easily use a custom algorithm to move forward using index in both list comparing them to each other until a match is found and alternating the search. Like that you can easily reduce both collection amount of item that is parsed each new compare reducing the check by alot. It's usable on all object with a valid comparer. But since the dictionary answer reduced your case to 3 seconds it would be micro-optimization that is not worth it at this point. 10m vs 10m would be something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you are using nested calls to `Any`, which is has an `O(n²)` complexity in the worst case.

You need to take advantage of `HashSet.Contains` which has an `O(1)` complexity:

```
var matches = sampleList
    .Where(kvp => resultList.Contains(kvp.Key))
    .Select(kvp => kvp.Value);
```

This now has `O(n)` complexity.

---

As for the use of `AsParallel()`, this is likely to have a negative impact on performance, because each partition is computationally inexpensive.

Comment: I can confirm that this is the proper answer. It does the same job in 3-4 seconds, where it previously took 40-50 seconds. Thank you good sir. P.S. I tested this without `AsParralel()`

Answer (score 0):

To start, you could replace `sampleList.Any(y => x == y.Key)` with `sampleList.ContainsKey(x);`

Secondly, not that it matters much, but you don't really get any benefit from using the `HashSet`, since you're pretty much just looping over the contents.

Depending on your data, you could look at other structures that would allow for faster lookup.

You could also try reversing your search, by trying to find values in the `HashSet` from the dictionary.

Comment: HashSet is used to remove duplicates and because I work with multithreading.

Comment: Remove duplicates fine, not sure what it has to do with multi threading here.